# search input data with where conditon in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

how to make search data with where condition? in here...

i have the table student

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_card` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `class` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `student_guardian` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `major` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

i make a CRUD with PHP and MYSQL, and then i make searching data with input type and button submit. but i wanna search  data where `major` is `Mathematic`, in this table i make input data major is `Mathematic`, `Science`, `Art`, `Music`

this is the condition that i want

```
SELECT * 
  FROM student 
 WHERE student.major = 'Mathematic'
```

this is the function for searching in input text :

```
function search_student($keyword) {
    $query = "
     SELECT * 
       FROM student
      WHERE id_card LIKE '%$keyword%' 
         OR name LIKE '%$keyword%' 
         OR student_guardian LIKE '%$keyword%' 
         OR student.major = 'Mathematic'
            ";
    return query($query);
}
```

this is the function too :

```
function query($query) {
    global $conn;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $rows = [];
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

when i searching, besides the Mathematic also appeared. what the problem?

Comment: _Side note:_ You should look into using parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of injecting the user data into the queries like that.

Comment: You are using multiple logical ORs (disjunctions), only one of those has to evaluate to true for a tuple to be included in the result. So you want to use an `AND` for `OR student.major = 'Mathematic'`. To ensure the major is restricted to Mathematics

Answer (score 1):

If you always want the major to be mathematics while any of the other files need to contain the keyword, then you need to group the WHERE conditions. Your current query will consider it a match if *any* of the conditions return true.

Something like this:

```
WHERE 
    (id_card LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR student_guardian LIKE ?) 
    AND major = 'Mathematic'
```

*Note:* I've replaced your manual injection of the variables with `?`, which is a placeholder for the value when you use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), which is highly recommended that you do.

Answer (score -1):

When you search, you want to have one of the parameters, and in the end the major will be Mathematic.

So you have to ask for a query and bring me all the lines where "name equal to" or 'student_guardian is equal to ... "
Plus(and) major = 'mathematics'

```
 SELECT * 
           FROM student
          WHERE (id_card LIKE '%$keyword%' 
             OR name LIKE '%$keyword%' 
             OR student_guardian LIKE '%$keyword%')
             **AND** student.major = 'Mathematic'
                ";
```